# Selenium multithreading

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Hey I am trying to make a automatic checkout bot, for now I made it so it can launch multiple undetected chrome instances :

```
driver = [(uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True ,options=options1)),(uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options2)),(uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options3))]
```

and it runs the code like that :

```
def Main1():
   i = 0
   login(i)
   checkout(i)
def Main2():
   i = 1
   login(i)
   checkout(i)
def Main3():
   i = 2
   login(i)
   checkout(i)
p1 = threading.Thread(target=Main1, args=())
p1.start()
p2 = threading.Thread(target=Main2, args=())
p2.start()
p3 = threading.Thread(target=Main3, args=())
p3.start()
```

`i` stands for driver and account details index.
What I wanted to ask is

1. how can I make this code more efficient? copying and pasting over and over doesn't seem like the most efficient thing
2. if I want to run x amount of instances, where all instances have different account details, and choose the amount if instances by inputting the value, how can I do it without manually creating a new function and adding another item to the driver list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to the question using the following code :

```
buynumber = int(input('Buy number : '))
threadlist = []
driver = []
option = []
for i in range(0, buynumber):
    threadlist.append(i)
threads = [threading.Thread(target=Main, args=(i,)) for i in threadlist]
for i in range(0, buynumber):
    option.append(Options())
    option[i].headless = True
    option[i].add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    option[i].add_argument("--incognito")
    option[i].add_argument("--headless")
for i in range(0, buynumber):
    driver.insert(i, uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,options=option[i]))
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

thanks to @Shuo for the help here

Answer (score 0):

Create a threads list, run them with loop.

```py
def instance(n):
    return [uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,options=option) for m in range(0, n)]


def Main(i):
   login(i)
   checkout(i)


threads = [threading.Thread(target=Main, args=(i,)) for i in instance(int(input('num of instances: ')))]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but I still have a few more questions : 
1. how can I choose how many threads will be used? if I want to use more than 3 instances can I choose the amount simply by doing `instances = input()`?
2. How can I make it so the code only launches the amount of undetected chromedriver instances I have chose, without needing to copy paste?

Comment: Did you mean you want to run instances simultaneously?